# Is it possible to find users within a geographical location

Tags: discussion, users, search, geography

I want to view the users on stackexchange that are from my country (mostly for programmers and stackoverflow)

Is there any way I can get this level of information?

Answer (score 4):

I come from the Netherlands and you can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/145580/top-dutch-users-stackoverflow) in the Data Explorer for that:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS [#], 
    Id AS [User Link], 
    Reputation
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    LOWER(Location) LIKE '%netherlands%'
ORDER BY
    Reputation DESC;
```

You can change it the way you want to of course.

Comment: Which, of course, assumes all people enter their location and that it is always correct. Both assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Of course. This is as close as you can get I think.